# iOS 8.x + AFNetworking memory growth

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I have an application that remains open for a long time, making periodic API calls to our server with AFNetworking 2.5.0.  On iOS 8.x, I'm seeing permanent memory growth with every API call which eventually leads to an out-of-memory crash.

I boiled away all my code to just use AFNetworking (and iOS underneath), and still see this memory growth.  Here's a very basic example that will recreate what I'm seeing: start the app and begin exercising HTTP GETs.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    // Don't block out text/html extensions, for this example.
    _manager.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];
    _manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/html", nil];

    [self getApiLoop];
    return YES;
}


- (void) getApiLoop {
    [_manager GET:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success!");

        // Do it again
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self getApiLoop];
        });

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure!");

        // Do it again
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self getApiLoop];
        });

    }];
}
```

I have run the same example on iOS 7.0, and do not see this same type of runaway memory growth.

Instruments suggests CFNetworking is malloc'ing and not releasing some memory underneath.

Any workarounds?  Do we need to file a bug with Apple?

Comment: Might be related to this AFNetworking issue: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2306 Try the fix mentioned in there and see if it works.

Comment: Also experiencing similar behaviour. OOM errors from repeated use of AFNetworking calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that is working well for my code base, happy to share it.

AFNetworking 2.x has 2 entry points:

- **AFHTTPSessionManager.m** - Recommended for apps that target iOS 7 and iOS 8
- **AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.m** - Recommended for apps that need to go back to iOS 6

My application requires iOS 6 and up, so I started with AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.m.  **Unfortunately, AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.m exhibits memory problems on iOS 8, whereas AFHTTPSessionManager.m does not (!)**.  Double unfortunately, the software APIs for these two managers are completely different.

My solution was to build an abstraction layer between AFNetworking and the rest of my application, which served 2 purposes for me: an app that works on iOS 6 and won't runaway with memory on iOS 8; and an abstraction layer that should prevent my team from having to edit every API call throughout my application every time AFNetworking changes.

My application does not necessarily need access to the full spectrum of features AFNetworking provides, so I only implemented what I needed:

- initWithBaseURL
- getResponseSerializer - (Explicitly named so we don't get confused)
- getRequestSerializer - (Explicitly named so we don't get confused)
- setResponseSerializer - (Explicitly named so we don't get confused)
- setRequestSerializer - (Explicitly named so we don't get confused)
- set headers with setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:
- GET
- PUT
- POST
- DELETE
- ... and the ability to cancel an operation

One advantage of an abstraction layer above AFNetworking is developers can effectively marshall in changes applied to AFNetworking underneath.  For example, as AFNetworking migrated from 1.x to 2.x, there was significant code-rework needed throughout everyone's applications to align with new APIs.  With an abstraction layer, you have the option of keeping your Application's APIs consistent while translating new AFNetworking APIs at one choke point, speeding up development.

I have shared my code under an Apache 2.0 license at:

https://github.com/eemoss/afnetworking-abstractionlayer-ios